# Enter-Pssession not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I have to machines in same network one with windows7 and another win windows server 2012.I tried Enter-PSsession on windows7 machine from server2012 machine...

```
       $ComputerName = "windows7-PC"
       $username="administrator"
       $password="password"
       $secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
       $password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
       $cr = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

       $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cr

        Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { echo '1' }
```

On doing same,i got an error

```
      New-PSSession : [windows7-PC] Connecting to remote server windows7-PC failed with the following error message : Access is denied.
      Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
```

argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

using same script i m able to execute 'echo 1' from windows7-pc to server2012-pc but not from server2012-pc to windows7-pc.

Comment: is remoting activated on the windows7 host ? try  `enable-psremoting -force`

Comment: @Kayasax yes it is activated. even WinRM quickconfig is done.

Comment: I had a similar problem times ago when a proxy was activated by mistake. could you verify the proxy setting in `$PSSessionOption `

Comment: @Kayasax no proxy is activated activated.actually i am able to enter into Pssession from win7 to win12 machine but not from win12 to win7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the remote server in trusted domain.

Please follow below article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

This will surely help you.

Comment: If the computers are in a workgroup, then I agree that this will help.